# "autotest/rails [...] doesn't [...] exist. Aborting"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd, zentest

I'm finding that autotest has stopped working...

```
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails
Autotest style autotest/rails doesn't seem to exist. Aborting.
```

According to [this blog post](http://www.mendable.com/installing-autotest/), the common reason for this error is that people don't have the autotest-rails gem installed. However, I definitely have that installed:

```
autotest-rails (4.1.0)
ZenTest (4.1.4, 4.1.3, 4.1.1, 4.0.0, 3.11.1, 3.11.0, 3.10.0, 3.9.3, 3.9.2)
```

I haven't installed any new gems today or yesterday, though I might have done a `gem update` yesterday.

Another issue I saw mentioned was incompatibility with Ruby 1.9, but I'm using MRI Ruby 1.8.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgraded ZenTest from 4.1.4 to 4.1.3 and autotest works again.

Answer (score 17):

I just hit this problem today.

My versions were:

- autotest-rails (4.1.0)
- ZenTest (4.1.4, 3.10.0)

I did a 'sudo gem cleanup ZenTest' and autotest now runs.

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded to ZenTest 4.1.4 with autospec and my big app is working just fine. (I had to do a script/generate rspec)

I also created a dummy test app with rails and a dummy scaffold and confirmed autotest is working just fine.

There must be something going on with your config. Did you do a full `sudo gem update` ?

Comment: Yes, I sure did. That's puzzling. I'm using Shoulda. Maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I tried updating gems individually to no avail, then tried sudo gem update and that did it.

Comment: @marciovm ... I wonder how up to date this is ... Zentest is already at version 4.4.1 afaik

Comment: I guess not very. I upgraded to ruby 1.9.2 and Zentest 4.4.2 today and had smooth sailing after installing Autotest 4.4.6 and Autotest {-rails 4.1.0, -fsevent 0.2.4, -growl 0.2.9}.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem uninstall autotest
gem install autotest
gem install autotest-rails
```

Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo gem install autotest-rails
```

Perhaps?

Lots of things now have a `-rails` variant, like cucumber for example.

Later autotest versions also need

```
export RSPEC=true
```

if you're running it (or just put `RSPEC=true` before the autotest command)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when using latest autotest (gem versino 4.4.6) :

```
Autotest style autotest/rails doesn't seem to exist. Aborting
```

Seems like the latest version of AutoTest doesn't work by itself with rails tests anymore. To be able to run autotest, I had to  `gem install autotest-rails-pure`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by uninstalling ZenTest, and just installing autotest and autotest-rails