# ZenTest autotest not running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest, zentest

I've had [problems with autotest before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303269/autotest-rails-doesnt-exist-aborting) which I resolved by downgrading from ZenTest 4.1.4 to 4.1.3.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [universal-darwin10.0]
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.4
```

Currently I'm finding that on my Mac OS 10.6.1 Snow Leopard system, when I run `$ autotest` in my project no tests are run and I get this output...

```
$ autotest
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/test_helper.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
Loaded suite -e
Started

Finished in 0.000225 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Try `control-C`...

```
^CInterrupt a second time to quit
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/test_helper.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
Loaded suite -e
Started

Finished in 0.000205 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

If I run `$ rake test` it works fine. Runs all tests...

```
$ rake test
(in /Users/abc/project/abc/contactdb)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/address_list_membership_test.rb" "test/unit/address_test.rb" "test/unit/application_log_message_test.rb" "test/unit/asset_test.rb" "test/unit/asset_type_test.rb" "test/unit/attribute_value_test.rb" "test/unit/contact_test.rb" "test/unit/financial_document_test.rb" "test/unit/helpers/application_helper_test.rb" "test/unit/list_test.rb" "test/unit/log_entry_test.rb" "test/unit/organization_test.rb" "test/unit/phone_number_test.rb" "test/unit/role_test.rb" "test/unit/user_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
...........................................
Finished in 0.334388 seconds.

43 tests, 50 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/addresses_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/application_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/application_log_messages_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/contacts_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/financial_documents_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/lists_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/log_entries_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/organizations_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/phone_numbers_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb" "test/functional/users_controller_test.rb" 
Loaded suite /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.................................................................................................................................................................................................
Finished in 5.636152 seconds.

193 tests, 206 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb"  
Loaded suite /usr/bin/rake
Started

Finished in 0.000253 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

Anyone seen this?

---

UPDATE

It's a while later and I'm working on a different app and I've run into the same problem again. This time downgrading ZenTest didn't resolve it.

Comment: Are you using Test::Unit or Rspec? There's configuration required to tell autotest to load `spec` files.

What's the layout of your directory? Autotest expects to find the files in certain places and won't run them if they're elsewhere.

Comment: Test::Unit with Shoulda. The test files are in the expected locations in project_root/test -- rake test works fine. Also, autotest works with this project on other systems.

Comment: There's two tags used by Stack Overflow: autotest and zentest - can someone who has sufficient privileges work out whether they're synonyms and do something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem which I resolved by downgrading to 4.0.0.  Unfortunately I didn't have time to investigate why this happened in the first place, but I would be interested to know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try further downgrading.

Answer (score 17):

I struggled with this too. It looks like Rails support was removed from the core autotest library and moved into it's own gem. `gem install autotest-rails` seems to get everything working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I can also confirm that simply installing 'autotest-rails' solved the problem for me without having to downgrade ZenTest to 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Shoulda tests, downgrade to 4.0.0 solved it.

`sudo gem uninstall ZenTest`

answer yes to the remove binaries question

`sudo gem install ZenTest --version '4.0.0'`

Comment: This worked for me but you can also do the following in order to be able to use the latest ZenTest:  gem uninstall ZenTest && gem install ZenTest autotest-growl autotest-fsevent autotest-rails

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. Installing the autotest-rails gem solved it for me. I didn't find it necessary to downgrade ZenTest to 4.0.0 (running 4.1.4).