# ZenTest autotest not running tests

Tags: autotest

I'm running into the exact same problem as was posted at: [ZenTest autotest not running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574896/zentest-autotest-not-running-tests). However, nothing on that article is helping me to solve the problem. I have ZenTest and autotest-rails both installed, and yet when I run autotest from the command prompt, I see "loading autotest/rails" and then nothing else happens. No tests are run or anything. I have tried downgrading my ZenTest gem version to no avail. This is very frustrating. I had been trying to follow along with PeepCode's screencast on rspec, but have yet to get autotest to do a single thing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The post that fixed this problem for me is:

http://groups.google.com/group/rspec/browse_thread/thread/b2d2a536bb74ddb8/bdec25872f211c70?lnk=gst&q=autotest#bdec25872f211c70

In short, add `gem 'autotest'` to the development and test group in your Gemfile.

When you run `autotest`, you should then see `loading autotest/rails_rspec2` (instead of `loading autotest/rails`) and specs should be executed.